# Hide computer from list, but keep file sharing and remote desktop service running?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, network-shares, lan, file-sharing

Is it possible to hide my computer from local network's list of computers, but keep its ability to provide file sharing and remote desktop service? (I mean something like hidden SSID on WiFi network, to let me use all functions when I know the name of my computer, but keep it hidden from other people who don't know the computer's name.)

Answer (score 2):

You can [disable network discovery](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enable-disable-network-discovery#1TC=windows-7), which will prevent other computers on your LAN from connecting to your computer except by IP address.

If you do this, and someone opens Remote Desktop or Windows Explorer and types in your computer name, they will get an error message, because this removes your computer from the NetBIOS system. But even still, your computer *may* (at your option) be available for connecting to it over Remote Desktop Protocol or File Sharing (Samba) protocol. You will need to use the `ipconfig` command-line tool (or other means of obtaining your Private IP) to know which IP to connect to from your other PCs.

Note that an IP address is not *security* by any stretch of the imagination. A modestly-skilled person could very quickly discover the IP address of your computer and then connect to it, even if you disable network discovery. A simple script that tries to connect to a bunch of IP addresses in a loop will find your IP on the private network within minutes. If you are trying to *protect* your data from being accessed by other people on your network (or on the public Internet, if you are directly connected without a NAT in between), you need to set up a firewall, and *at least* password-based authentication for services you choose to expose (such as File and Printer Sharing).

Turning off network discovery is a bit like "hiding" your car keys in your sock drawer. Someone can still open the drawer, take the keys and drive your car. They just have to look for them a little bit first.

Comment: I think firewall cannot help me here. If I keep file sharing and remote desktop services running, people can connect regardless of firewall.

Comment: @AlKepp You can block certain IPs using a firewall, while only allowing certain IPs. For example, if you have a network of 6 computers, and you only want to allow a connection to your computer from two of the others, you can configure the Windows firewall to drop all inbound packets from the unwanted computers. OR you can block all inbound connections by default, but add an exception to explicitly tell it that it's OK to allow connections from specific IP addresses. This won't address the problem of someone using one of the other PCs if you don't want them to, but that's what passwords are for

Comment: Anyway, my answer is correct: disabling network discovery will "hide" the computer from the "Networks" list in Windows Explorer. This answers your question, but it may not provide enough security to satisfy you. Either way, this is what you asked for. You should consider "Accepting" this answer (click the check mark).

Comment: That LAN uses DHCP, so computers have got dynamic IP addresses and IP filtering won't help me. I just wanted to hide the computer from the list (in Explorer). But I tested it at home and I can see my computer and can connect to its network shares from the other computer even when network discovery is disabled.

Comment: How about if you try to [disable NetBIOS](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fo4w4.png)?

Answer (score 1):

### To hide your computer name so that it does not display in your network:

In the command prompt, type in the command below and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
Net config server /hidden:yes
```

You will get a message saying “The command completed successfully”.

### To unhide your computer name so that it does display in your network:

In the elevated command prompt, type in the command below and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
Net config server /hidden:no
```

You will get a message saying “The command completed successfully”.

Exit the command prompt and then restart the computer to apply changes.

Comment: How do you make this permanent?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, in addition to the above two answers, was disabling the "Function Discovery Resource Publication" service. The HomeGroup Provider depends on it, so it must be disabled too.

```
::Disable Network Discovery (public/private)
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="Network Discovery" new enable=no
::Hide computer name
net config server /hidden:yes
::Disable HomeGroupProvider/FDResPub services
net stop HomeGroupProvider
sc config HomeGroupProvider start= disabled
net stop FDResPub
sc config FDResPub start= disabled
```

A reboot, or at least disconnecting from the network and reconnecting, may be needed.