# Hide Samba server name from Network view in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, samba

Samba Server: CentOS7 with Samba 4.7.1 / Clients: Windows 7

So far I tried adding these options under `[global]` in `smb.conf`, but the server is still visible in Network (or running `net view`), even after rebooting the client(s).

```
lm announce = no
local master = no
browsable = no
browse list = no
```

It's possible to do this with a Windows PC (see: [Hide computer from list, but keep file sharing and remote desktop service running?](https://superuser.com/questions/743522/hide-computer-from-list-but-keep-file-sharing-and-remote-desktop-service-runnin)). Can it be done with Samba?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple: disable the nmb service.
`systemctl stop nmb && systemctl disable nmb`

I also left the following under the `[global]` section in `smb.conf`, however the server doesn't show either way.

```
lm announce = no 
local master = no 
browse list = no 
disable netbios = yes
```

As harrymc pointed out, the samba server is still accessible by its IP address.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking for the same solution as in the link but for samba,
then disabling network discovery in samba as simple enough.

Add to the `smb.conf` this option:

```
disable netbios = yes
```

You will still be able to access the samba server by its IP address.

Comment: It didn't work for me... however it pointed me to the right solution. I had to stop and disable the nmb service. Now it doesn't show up anymore. Thanks!